# for loop adds results from previous loops

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have made a programm that computes the frequency of a 2D array and i want it to give me the results for every row(for every i). But when i add the for loop `for(i=0;i<S1;i++)`it computes the frequency for the 1st row right and in the 2nd one for instance it adds the frequencies of the 1st row to the 2nd and so on.How can i prevent it from adding the frequencies?Any suggestions? Thanks :)

edit:to make my problem more clear:If i add  the numbers {10 20 30 30 30 30 20 30 10}

> i should expect to receive the following result :

```
1st row    0-9        0
          10-19       1
          20-29       1
          30-39       1   from the row {10 20 30}
2nd row   0-9         0
          10-19       0
          20-29       0
          30-39       3    from the row {30 30 30}
 3rd row  0-9          0
          10-19        1
          20-29        1
          30-39        1  from the row {20 30 10}
```

> Instead of getting these results i get

```
       1st row 

       0-9        0
      10-19       1
      20-29       1
      30-39       1   
    from the row {10 20 30}
    2nd row   0-9         0
              10-19       2
              20-29       2
              30-39       2    from the row {30 30 30}
     3rd row  0-9          0
              10-19        3
              20-29        3
              30-39        3 from the row {20 30 10}




 #include <stdio.h>
 #define   S1      3                                      
 #define   COUNTER 11   
 #define   S2      3              

 int main() {                                                           
   float A[S1][S2];

   int i, j, k, low, high;                              
   int group[COUNTER] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};  

   for (i = 0; i < S1; i++) {                
     for (j=0; j < S2; j++) {                                               
        scanf("%f", &A[i][j]);                             
     }                                                       
   }  

   for(i=0; i < S1; i++) {
     for(j=0; j < S2; j++) {
       ++ group[(int)(A[0][j] + 0.5 ) / 10];
     }

     printf("\n");                                           
     printf("GROUP     RANGE     FREQUENCY\n\n") ;          
     for(k = 0; k < COUNTER; k++) {                                                       
       low = k * 10;                                      
       if(k == 10)                                          
         high = 100;                                       
       else                                                 
         high = low + 9;                                   
       printf("%2d    %3d to %3d       %d\n",             
               k+1, low, high, group[k]);                 
     }
   }             
   getch();                                                
 }
```

Comment: Your code formatting is just mind-blowing.

Comment: please elaborate the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize your array to contain all zeroes upon going to the next row. Perhaps this will work for you:

```
for(i=0; i < S1; i++) {
   memset(group, 0, sizeof(group));
   for(j=0; j < S2; j++) {
      ++ group[(int)(A[0][j] + 0.5 ) / 10];
      // The rest of your code here.
```

Also, if you are trying to get the frequency for each row, shouldn't you be looking at the value stored at `A[i][j]`, instead of `A[0][j]`?

Comment: Yep you are right about the A[i][j] but even if i change it i don't get the results i want.Specifically i get                                                                   >  1st row 

       0-9        0
      10-19       1
      20-29       1
      30-39       1   
    from the row {10 20 30}
    2nd row   0-9         0
              10-19       2
              20-29       2
              30-39       4    from the row {30 30 30}
     3rd row  0-9          0
              10-19        2
              20-29        2
              30-39        5 from the row {20 30 10}

Comment: Yep,now it's perfect.Thank you for your time :)